# Change back from LCD driver

Tags: touchscreen, pi-3b+, vnc, screen, lcd

I've successfully installed [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/3-5-inch-Raspberry-Pi-3-Model-B-Touchscreen-480-320-LCD-Display-Touch-Pen-ABS/32906213419.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.3da24c4dOkTXCx) 3.5" LCD display, which uses this LCD driver: https://github.com/goodtft/LCD-show.

My problem is, that when I use VNC to remotely access the PI, (I assume) because of the LCD driver the resolution is too small and I can only see part of the windows and can't change resolution. Why can't I change the resolution?
Any idea how to solve the problem? Can I somehow delete the driver or revert to the original display configuration? Unfortunately I only have remote access to the PI right know. (BTW I'm using RealVNC and PI 3B+)

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the last part of the Step 3 from [RAEDME.md](https://github.com/goodtft/LCD-show/blob/master/README.md) file of the GitHub repo you are referring to.

> If you need to switch back to the traditional HDMI display
>
> `sudo ./LCD-hdmi`

Login into your pi using ssh and `cd` to the location where you downloaded the driver and executed **./LCDxx-show** previously and run the command `sudo ./LCD-hdmi`