# Raspberry Pi 4 Installed screen drivers but disabled my hdmi

Tags: raspbian, hdmi, touchscreen, driver, pi-4

I bought a touchscreen and installed the drivers for it, but now my hdmi doesn't work. I am currently running Raspbian on Raspberry Pi 4 model B.And I have a 3.5 inch tft screen.I do not no what driver I have. I got it through my terminal from the github. They gave me a command for the terminal to enable the hdmi but it doesen't work. They said that once I installed the driver it would disable my hdmi, but they said you could enable it by executing this command: sudo ./LCD-hdmi. The exact name of my screen is: MHS-3.5 inch Display. Can you guys help me?

Comment: Hi @Julian, If you are installing an ILI9341 type touch screen driver, the following post might help: LCD TFT screen 2.8" ILI9341 SPI Connect： https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98549/lcd-tft-screen-2-8-ili9341-spi-connect/98557#98557

Comment: What touchscreen? What drivers? What Raspberry Pi? What operating system? Please edit your question and add missing information to it.

Comment: @Julian See the answer from Ravi Mali in the following post. It implies that the sudo ./LCD-hdmi command must be executed from the same directory where you executed the MHS35-show command. You were not specific about how the sudo ./LCD-hdmi command "doesen't work". https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/93023/change-back-from-lcd-driver The docs here show you doing a "cd LCD-show" before MHS-35-show. Make sure you are in the directory where the LCD-show executable resides. http://www.lcdwiki.com/MHS-3.5inch_RPi_Display#How_to_use_in_the_Raspberry.2FUbuntu_Mate.2FKali.2FRetropie_system

Answer (score 1):

The command `sudo ./LCD-hdmi` will run a script that uncomments the line `hdmi_force_hotplug=1` in Raspberry PI Config File which will force raspbian to use HDMI instead of the touchscreen. If you do this, you will have to comment the line `hdmi_force_hotplug=1` everytime you want to use your touchscreen instead of the HDMI. I hope this helps.